# Find the Sufficient Statistic for $\beta$

Tags: statistics

The pdf is given by $$f(x|\beta) = \frac{1}{\beta+1} e^{-\frac{x}{\beta+1}}.$$

To find the sufficient statistic, we would find the Likelihood

$L[\beta] = \frac{1}{(\beta+1)^n} e^{-\frac{∑x_i}{\beta+1}}$

But how do we find the sufficient statistic for $\beta$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Factorization Theorem.  The goal is to express the joint density as $$f(\boldsymbol x \mid \beta) = g(\boldsymbol T(\boldsymbol x) \mid \beta) h(\boldsymbol x)$$ for some sufficient statistic $\boldsymbol T(\boldsymbol x)$.  Clearly, the joint density can be regarded as a function of $\beta$ and $\sum x_i$, rather than as a function of the sample $\boldsymbol x = (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$.  That is to say, if you only know the **sum** of the observations in the sample, rather than the sample itself, you can calculate the joint density.  So the sample total is **a** sufficient statistic:  $$T(\boldsymbol x) = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$$ is sufficient for $\beta$.  (Note that the $T$ is not in bold because it is scalar-valued; i.e., $T : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$.)  Of course, the sample mean $\bar x$ is also sufficient, being the sample total divided by the sample size.  The sample itself is also a sufficient statistic; i.e., $$\boldsymbol T(\boldsymbol x) = \boldsymbol x$$ is trivially sufficient, but it achieves no data reduction.